# OTRS 3.0: Agent notes by email - notifications

Tags: otrs

My goal is that agents can attach notes to a ticket by email.
I have set up a second mail address ticketnotes@... which is filtered by a PostMaster Filter. In this way I can set the *X-OTRS-[FollowUp-]ArticleType* header to *note-internal* and *X-OTRS-[FollowUp-]SenderType* to *agent* and the email gets attached as agent note to the ticket mentioned in the subject. That works quite well. The problem is that the subsequent notifications emails are of the type *Agent::FollowUp* and not *Agent::AddNote*. That is confusing my agents.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followups are when a user mails an email. You will want to set the header. Set this field: `X-OTRS-FollowUp-ArticleType`

see the code:

```
 ArticleType      => $GetParam{'X-OTRS-FollowUp-ArticleType'},
```

http://tesisitil.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk/otrs-2.4.5/Kernel/System/PostMaster/FollowUp.pm

see also: http://forums.otterhub.org/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=4966